# How can i move code from a frame to another so i can create a menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

i'm creating a videogame and so far i've been messing with it on the frame 1 since it's code just needed a frame to run, altho, now i have come to the place where i want to create a menu, and so i was thinking about coding it each frame being a menu and using `gotoAndStop()` to jump in between frames. Problem is, if i move my frame 1 to, let's say, frame 10 so i can play main menu at frame 1 the code stops working. I am very confused on what i should do and i'm not sure i am even being clear enough.

Should i place full code here, let me know.

How can i move the code from frame to frame 10 properly so it still works!

Answer (score 1):

Forget the Frame approach. Nest your menu inside a MovieCLip, there u can use as many frames as u need and add that in your Main Frame.
It would be better to forget Framescript alltogether and use a Document Class, especially for a Game!

To your problem, dont put any keyframes other then the First one (with the code in it) in your actionsLayer. Put the stop() commmands und menu functions in a sepperate layer

Comment: i am using a document class, if it is what i think, i am programming the game in flashdevelop aswell, i will try that approach. basically one key should bring up the menu (movieclip) right?

Comment: hi again, is there a way we could chat? I can't find a email or skype or anyother sort of contact for you, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sry mate, i dont put private information out in public. But i can open a chatroom here on SO. Remind me here tomorrow, it's kinda late 2day. l8rs

Comment: can you open and give the link of a chatroom ? :) ty